# Redirect http to https in Django (using sslserver)

Tags: django, https, redirect

I have a django project working with HTTPS using django [sslserver](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver).I want `http` to be redirected to `https`. I tried adding `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` which does not seem to have any effect.

Similarly to test if my redirection was right, I tried the following on a test project.

1. Created a new django project
2. Added `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` to the `settings.py` file. Here now, when I try to run the server with `http` it redirects to `https`. But asof now my server does not support `https` cause of which desired web page is not displayed.
3. Installed `sslserver`
4. Ran the project with the command `python manage.py runsslserver 8000`
5. This succesfully redirects the webpage to `https` even if I open the url with `http`

This test redirection works fine like this. But if I already have `sslserver` installed ssl redirection does not seem to have any effect. I have been stuck with this problem for a while now and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` settings works together with `SecurityMiddleware`.

Try add it to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py`.

Comment: i have `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=True` and `SecurityMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE` list. I am running server using `./manage.py runsslserver` but when i try to visit a page over `http`, it doesn't load anything. it works with `https`. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=True in settings.py as mentioned, you need both

1. runsslserver on port 443
2. runserver on port 80

To have another service listen on port 80 for incoming http requests and do the redirect.

That works for me.

Answer (score -1):

try adding to your settings.

```
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'
```

Comment: `ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL` is not a django setting.